# Expectation related to Normal distribution and its density

Tags: probability, inequality, random-variables

Given $\sigma^2>0$. Let $Z\sim N(0,1)$ and $\Phi$ be the cumulative standard normal with density function $\phi$. I wish to show that
$$
E\left(\frac{Z^2}{[\phi(\sigma Z)]^2}\Phi(\sigma Z)[1-\Phi(\sigma Z)]\right)<\infty.
$$

This is what I have done:

Note that $\Phi(\sigma Z)[1-\Phi(\sigma Z)]\le \frac14, a.s.$ So, we have
\begin{align}
E\left(\frac{Z^2}{[\phi(\sigma Z)]^2}\Phi(\sigma Z)[1-\Phi(\sigma Z)]\right)&\le E\left(\frac{Z^2}{[\phi(\sigma Z)]^2}\right)\\
&=2\pi E\left(Z^2e^{\sigma^2Z^2}\right)\\
&\le \pi \left[E(Z^4)+E(e^{2\sigma^2Z^2})\right].
\end{align}
The last equation would be finite if $\sigma^2<\frac14$. However, there is no upper bound on my problem. Any suggestion?

Comment: You were probably too wasteful throwing away the $\Phi$ term.

Comment: I seem to get this to be true only when $\sigma< 1$... and that might sense somewhat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe what you claim only holds for $\sigma<1$

I am going to truncate the expectation at a large positive $c$, i.e. We will just look at the tail of the the integral. The thing you asked for is finite iff the following integral is finite (by symmetry of $Z$, $\phi$ and $\Phi(\cdot)(1-\Phi(\cdot))$, we do not need to look at the tail at $-\infty$).

$$ I = E(... 1_{Z>c})$$

Note there exists $c$ such that for $x>c$, (by the Mill's ratio for normal distribution), the following holds:

$$\frac{1}{2x}\leq \frac{1-\Phi(ax)}{\phi(ax)}\leq \frac{1}{x}$$

so you just need to look at

$$J = \int^\infty_c \frac{x^2}{\phi(ax)} \exp\bigg(-\frac{x^2}{2}\bigg)\text{d}x$$

and

$$ \frac{1}{2}\Phi(a c) J \leq I\leq J$$

then $$J =\int^\infty_c x^2\exp\bigg(-\frac{(1-\sigma^2)x^2}{2}\bigg)\text{d}x$$

which is finite if and only if $\sigma^2<1$

Comment: Yep, converges iff $\sigma\lt1$. +1.

Comment: Very nice @Lost1. It turned out that I made very weak bound for $\Phi(1-\Phi).$ Thank you very much for your help and time. +1